# Crashes when trying to generate multiples of the same process(Access Violation Error)

Tags: c, string, windows, process, widechar

So, when trying to create multiple processes of the same program I am getting an access violation error when I try to create the second child process. (I am able to create one child process before it crashes trying to create the second child process)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "lol")) ThreadFunc();

    char key_code;
    int i = 0;

    STARTUPINFO* si = calloc(1, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    PROCESS_INFORMATION* pi = calloc(1, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    WCHAR** wideArguments = calloc(1, sizeof(wchar_t*));
    size_t outSize;
    size_t size = strlen(arguments) + 1;

    while (1) {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            key_code = _getch();
            if (key_code == 'c') {
                i += 10;
                si = realloc(si, i * sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
                pi = realloc(pi, i * sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
                wideArguments = realloc(wideArguments, i * sizeof(wchar_t*));
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                    wideArguments[i + k - 10] = calloc(256, sizeof(wchar_t));
                    GetModuleFileName(NULL, wideArguments[i + k - 10], 256);
                    wcscat_s(wideArguments[i + k - 10], 256, L" lol");
                    int l = CreateProcess(NULL, wideArguments[i + k - 10], NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si[i + k - 10], &pi[i + k - 10]);
                    if (l == 0) printf("\n\n%d\n\n", GetLastError());
                }
            }
            else if (key_code == 'x') {
                free(si);
                free(pi);
                for(int j = 0; j < i;j++) free(wideArguments[j];
                free(wideArguments);
                exit(0);        
            }
        }
        else continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `realloc` does not zero the memory, as `calloc` does.

Comment: Possibly the buffer for `GetModuleFileName` and `wscat_s` are too small. Check the return values.

Comment: Typo: `for(int j = 0; j < i;i++)` should be `j++`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it is not too small, because the 1 process is created successfully, it crashed when it tries to run the CreateProcess line a second

Comment: `si[i + k - 10]` is not initialized in the call to `CreateProcess`! See the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, i think that is the problem will give a check.

Comment: yeah, the si and pi arrays were a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The problem is that `realloc` does not zero the memory thus the entries in pi and si weren't being initialized. To fix this we define a `piOriginal` and `siOriginal` that we use to initialize the entries on the array later.

```
STARTUPINFO siOriginal = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION piOriginal = { 0 };
```

And change the loop after the 'c' input to:

```
if (key_code == 'c') {
                i += 10;
                si = realloc(si, i * sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
                pi = realloc(pi, i * sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
                wideArguments = realloc(wideArguments, i * sizeof(wchar_t*));
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                    wideArguments[i + k - 10] = calloc(256, sizeof(wchar_t));
                    si[k + i - 10] = siOriginal;
                    pi[k + i - 10] = piOriginal;
                    GetModuleFileName(NULL, wideArguments[i + k - 10], 256);
                    wcscat_s(wideArguments[i + k - 10], 256, L" lol");
                    int l = CreateProcess(NULL, wideArguments[i + k - 10], NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si[i + k - 10], &pi[i + k - 10]);
                    if (l == 0) printf("\n%d\n", GetLastError());
                }
            }
```